# literal translation of se douter?

Tags: vocabulaire

In Camus’ La Peste there is a passage where Tarrou makes an offer to Rieux. Rieux replies:

> Bien entendu, vous vous doutez que j’accepte avec joie.

What would be a good literal translation? My attempt:

> Of course, you suspect that I will accept with joy

doesn’t seem right. Can *se douter* have the sense of *anticipate*? I don't find that sense in the bilingual dictionaries I've consulted.

(I’ve seen the passage translated as:

> I need hardly tell you that I accept your suggestion most gladly

but I'm more interested in a literal translation and, in particular, the sense of se douter.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Se douter* means indeed to suspect , but also, depending on the context, "to infer", "to guess, based on the information one has". This the meaning here.

*Vous vous doutez que* (and variants) is a common way to express politely what you expect your interlocutor thinks (or should think), something like "as you can guess..."

Ex:

> Vous vous doutez que je ne travaille pas le dimanche. (= I guess you understand I don't work on Sundays)

The translation "I need hardly tell you that I accept your suggestion most gladly" conveys that meaning with the same level of language. Maybe a more literal translation would be this: "you will certainly guess I accept your suggestion".

Comment: Thank you. I find this answer to be the most helpful, especially the remark that using vous vous doutez is a common way to express politely what you expect your interlocutor thinks.

Answer (score 1):

"Se douter" means "to have some slight knowledge (of sth)" ("*avoir une idée*" in the definition below).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/douter)) II. Emploi pronom. à valeur subjective. Se douter (de), (que). Avoir (une) idée de quelque chose, croire sur certains indices à une chose qu'on peut redouter. Être loin de se douter, avoir l'air de se douter de/que. (Quasi-) synon. conjecturer, deviner, pressentir, soupçonner.

Therefore "to have an inkling" corresponds well enough ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/inkling?q=inkling)).

> a slight knowledge of something that is happening or about to happen

- It is obvious that you must have an inkling that I accept your suggestion gladly.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This answer resolves my difficulty, but I found an alternative answer slightly more enlightening.